# What does djangos unique=true actually do?

Tags: mysql, django

I assume it verifies that the field is unique to all other entries in the same table. But what happens if there actually is a collision? Does django just crash? Or does it just keep rerunning the default generator until it has found a value that is unique? 
Can I just use any crappy random number/string generator I want and assume that django will ensure that a unique value is always set?
In which case, if all values are taken, does it just fall into an endless loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume it verifies that the field is unique to all other entries in the same table.

It makes that specific field unique, so that means that there can not exists two entities with the same value (at the same time). It is important to note that the uniqness constraint does *not* hold for `NULL` values: indeed two or more records can simultanously exists where the unique column has `NULL` for all these records.

The uniqness is normally enforced at the database level (given the database can enforce that). In case you create a record with a value that is already taken, the creation will raise an `IntegrityError`. Indeed, it will raise something like:

```
>>> Model.objects.create(name='foo')
<Model: Model object (1)>
>>> Model.objects.create(name='foo')
⋮
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'foo' for key 'model_name_72507083_uniq'")
```

It will thus *not* rerun the default constructor. You are responsible to make sure that the generator each time will construct a valid value. It will thus not ge stuck in an infinite loop, but raise an error if the default filled in by a function already exists.

Comment: Is there an elegant way around this? Because I'd like to use about 10-12 characters for -conveniences and its not impossible there will be a collision at some point, especially with a fast generator. I think UUIDs are just way to long to share as links

Comment: @user2741831: no, for example `AutoSlug` uses a loop as well: https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug/blob/3a87391ae7a5141d06396b93ee5b4030d9790a14/autoslug/utils.py#L69 In Yesod (Haskell's web framework), I developed something to transparently encrypt and decrypt the primary key, which thus does not have a burden on the database, and still is quite random. But I don't think there is a way to circumvent that. In fact if one does not use transactions, it is even possible that repeating the generation process still results in a duplicate, due to a race condition.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into this further. Maybe Ill just stick with UUIDs, since having to check and fetch the db everytime I add an entry seams very slow